# linq to entity where clause on complex join(inner object)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following class design. The where clause is not right on the generated linq with entity framework for wholesaler object.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public Brand Brand {get;set;}
}
public class Brand
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public Business Supplier {get;set;}
    public IList<WholesalerBrand> WholesalerBrand {get;set;}
}
public class Business
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
public class WholesalerBrand
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int Brand_Id {get;set;}
    public int Buisness_Id {get;set;}

    public Brand Brand {get;set;}
    public Business Wholesaler {get;set}
}
```

So the business logic is: Product belongs to Brand. Brand belongs to a Supplier(which is a business object) and brand can have multiple wholesalers. This relation is described in WholesalerBrand class.

In entity framework, the queryable object looks like this.

```
IQueryable<Product> query = context.Product.Include(b => b.Brand).Include(s => s.Brand.Business).Include(wb => wb.Brand.WholesalerBrand).Include(w => w.Brand.WholesalerBrand.Select(i => i.Business));
```

Now the supplier information can be queried like this:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.Brand.Business.Name.Contains(name)); ---- the generated linq has the Where on correct object.
```

But where is applied on a wrong level of business object in this query:

```
query = query.Where(w => w.Brand.WholesalerBrand.Any(b => b.Wholesaler.Name.Contains(name))); --- thus giving wrong set of rows.
```

How do i query on wholesaler business in this scenario. What is going wrong here? Please help.

I can share the generated linq in case if anyone needs it.

**[Updated]**
User needs to search for Supplier and/or wholesaler info from web page. The application is using entity framework and the queries I am using is shown above. The wholesaler is defined through a mapping class WholesalerBrand. The search context entity is the Product. When i query for wholesaler through this query

```
query = query.Where(w => w.Brand.WholesalerBrand.Any(b => b.Wholesaler.Name.Contains(name)));
```

The where clause is applied at the wrong level object. Hence, the search results are wrong. so I need a way to query for wholesaler information through Entity Framework.

Comment: Shouldn't `b.Business` in the last query be `b.Wholesaler`?

Comment: Wholesaler is a Business object, So it is Business.

Comment: I meant, in your sample model the property is called `Wholesaler` - `public Business Wholesaler {get;set}`

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this question not answered? I am also looking for better way to achieve this. Any suggestion to change the approach or the table/model design. How can one get help here from expertise?

Comment: Because it's unclear what is the question/problem/goal. Also as I mentioned in the previous comments, the properties of the classes do not match the properties used in queries. Edit your question to include correct property names and formulate the problem - what are you getting with the last query, what is wrong with that and what is the desired result.

Comment: updated the original post and query as per your suggestion. Thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: Good, but I still don't understand what do you mean by *"the where clause is applied at the wrong level object"* and what **exactly** is wrong with the result. Let take it this way - your query returns the products which brand is associated with at least one wholesaler matching the name parameter. There could be more wholesalers associated with that product brand. What's wrong with that? What is the expected (correct) result? Are you trying to return filtered `Product.Brand.WholesalerBrand` collection??

Comment: The tricky thing is returning businesses/wholesalers from product context. Say for example, I am trying to query for wholesaler whose name contains with 'country%'. This is done from this query, 
    query = query.Where(w => w.Brand.WholesalerBrand.Any(b => b.Wholesaler.Name.Contains(name)));

Comment: continued......
The result i get from this is wrong when i run a query in management studio with inner joins like
    select distinct b.name from product p inner join brand r on p.brand_id = r.id inner join Wholesaler_Brand wb on wb.brand_id=r.id inner join business b on b.id = wb.business_id where b.dba_name like '%country%'